# Android Slide in and out animation issue

Tags: android, android-animation

My Activity Successfully slide in android 4.1 from Activity A to B using animation

```
**inamation.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
android:fromXDelta="100%"
android:toXDelta="0%"
android:duration="600" />
</set>
```

and

**outanimation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
android:fromXDelta="100%"
android:toXDelta="0%"
android:duration="600" />
</set>
```

and in activity A i used overidding pending transition as shown below:

A.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.outanimation,R.anim.inanimation);

as said earlier this works fine on android 4 and above platform but when i 
test it on android 2.3 platform, Activity A to B gets android default activity animation.

how can i run my activity to slide left to right and right to left which is compatible with 2.2 and above.

**Is there a way to set animation between two activities programmatically ?**

**UPDATE**

***The problem was that the device, at least in the case of Samsung Galaxy, has to have animations enabled for this to work. This can be done in the settings menu.***

**Do you know how to activate all animation from settings Menu in Android ?**

Comment: If the user has explicitly disabled the animations in the menu, you shouldn't try to override this setting (if it's even possible, which I doubt).

Comment: in android 4.0 and above this option has been remove from device. But i want animation to activate on my application. specially Sliding between activities

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Android Slide in and out animation, I have use following code.

**Activity A :**

```
Intent intnt = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                        CustomTabActivity.class);
                startActivity(intnt);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,
                        R.anim.slide_out_left);
                finish();
```

**slide_in_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p" />
```

**slide_out_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p" />
```

Comment: Hello @Hardik, yes the animation and logic was good its just the some mobile phone like samsung (my testing device) has animation turned off. All animations should be turned on to enable activity sliding

Comment: Thanks you for your response but its not my answer, but i tried it and it works.

Comment: @Dimitri then please add how you solve this. So that it may help others.

Comment: just turn animation on manually on phone device settings (Menu-Settings-Display-Animation-ALL ANIMATIONS). for the time being i don't know how to turn animation on programmatically for the application

Comment: Ok @Dimitri congratulations again :)