# Android 5.0 Slide Animation Flashing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm looking to use the [Slide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Slide.html) Transition class added in the Android SDK 21. Currently I have this code to replace my fragment:

```
    Fragment fragment = getFragment(fragmentManager);

    Slide slide = new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT);
    fragment.setEnterTransition(slide);


    fragmentManager.beginTrSlideansaction()
        .replace(R.id.content, fragment, getKey())
        .commit();
```

The Slide animation works for the fragment coming into view, but the fragment that currently existed in the R.id.content container flashes white instead of sliding off the opposite side.

Any ideas what I may be missing?

Comment: I also encountered this when using it as an enter transition for activities. The problem with using the old xml animations is that before starting the animation the navigation bar and status bar flashes black, when you are in immersive mode or paint them in a different color.  Have you ever found a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I was mistaken in thinking that this Slide animation handles the exit transition. The white flash happens because the old fragment is removed instantly and the new one slides in from the right side.

To get the full animation I just did it the old way using [XML Animations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16477125/882782)